# Install a fastboot rom in redmi 5A if the phone get bricked or stuck in bootloop?

Tags: android

I am thinking to flash TWRP custom recovery in my Redmi 5A(RIVA). but last time when I tried to do it it ended up in a bootloop so I had to take it to the service center. so I want to know if I could flash a fastboot rom even if the phone stuck in bootloop on end up in bricking.

Comment: SO is for programming questions only.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.

> so I want to khow if I could flash a fastboot rom even if the phone stuck in bootloop on end up in bricking.

Are you asking if it'll bootloop again or get bricked if you flash a custom ROM over it?
There are chances, but not so much if you do it right.

Is your phone bootlooping, but you're able to access fastboot?
You can try flashing TWRP recovery if that's not there. You can also try the adb way.

I think [XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) is a better forum to discuss your issue.